# How can I execute the md5sum command on the files stored in this array in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, unix, md5, md5sum

I am running a perl script to calculate the md5sum of each file in a directory.  So far, I have the filenames stored in a @files array.  I want to call md5sum system command on each filename in the array and print the output to standard output?

Here is what i have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

@files = <*>;
foreach $file (@files) {
print $file . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use md5sum, you should use [`Digest::MD5`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Digest/MD5.html) module. If you insist on using the system's command, `` my $digest = `md5sum $file`; `` will store the result into a variable.